# Pass parameter between 2 controllers rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to solve this for quite some time and I need a fresh pair of eyes.

A conversation has user1, user2 and can have many messages. 
A message has user and body and belongs to a conversation.

In my `conversations controller` inside the `show` method I have a way to get all messages that belong to a conversation:

```
@conversation = Conversation.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @conversation.messages.any?
      @messages = @conversation.messages
    end
param_to_pass = @conversation.user2
@message = Message.new
```

and I also create a new `message model` to pass it to the form present inside `show.html.erb` 
`form for @message`

Once the form is submitted I get access to the params submitted, but I would also like to pass from the `conversation controller` to the `messages controller` that value `param_to_pass`. How can I achieve this?

In my messages controller in the `create` method I'm using

```
message = Message.new(message_params)
```

Is it possible to use the `@message` created inside the `conversation controller` and just add the extra `message_params` submitted by the form?
I could just add a field to the messages model 'param_to_pass' and add it from the `conversation controller` like `@message.param_to_pass = param_to_pass`.

Is there anything else I can post to make the issue clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `session` to share data between submissions, so in your conversation controller you would do

```
session[:params_to_pass] = @conversation.user_2
```

and in your message controller

```
@message.params_to_pass = session[:params_to_pass]
```

However... the amount of data you can save in session is limited.  So better would be to just pass ID's.

```
session[:params_to_pass] = @conversation.user_2.id
```

and

```
@message.params_to_pass = User.find_by(id: session[:params_to_pass])
```

Comment: Thank you. This sounds like a working approach. There are going to be a lot of messages. Are there going to be any downsides in creating and updating/destroying the session a lot of times?

Comment: It's what the session exists for. The limitation is mostly size, since session store is usually cookie store so is about 4k... A bit less due to overheads.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is pretty common, and it's rare to pass around params in a session.

If you're creating messages, the most common approach would be to post to the messages controller, not the conversations controller (this would be RESTful). From the messages controller, you could probably find a way to either redirect back to the conversation from `message#create` or possibly, AJAX post to messages and respond with a js response to add the new message html to the bottom of the conversation message list.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after implementing the session and used form_tag.